# jQuery wrapAll not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery

I am trying to wrap a generated series of elements that are created on the fly with another element, for example:

```
var innerHtmlAsText = "<li>test1</li><li>test2</li>";
var wrapper = "<ul />";

$("div#target").append($(innerHtmlAsText).wrapAll(wrapper));
```

My expected result is

```
<ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
</ul>
```

But the actual result is:

```
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
```

The `li` elements are not wrapped. In my instance the innerHtml is generated on the fly from a user generated template and the wrapper is supplied separately. How can I get the inner values wrapped?

Comment: `$(wrapper).append(innerHtmlAsText).appendTo('div#target');` would do the same, without the nested jQuery calls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`wrapAll` returns the original jQuery object, not the new one.  So, `wrapAll` is returning the `<li>`s, because that's the object that `wrapAll` was called on.

Try this:

```
$("div#target").append($(innerHtmlAsText).wrapAll(wrapper).parent());
```

Answer (score 3):

That happens because `wrapAll` does not return the wrapper, but the original object it was applied to (*as most jquery functions*).

Use the `.parent()` to get to the `ul` element..

```
$("div#target").append( $(innerHtmlAsText).wrapAll(wrapper).parent() );
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible only with `.append()`.

```
var innerHtmlAsText = "<li>test1</li><li>test2</li>";
var wrapper = "<ul/>";

$("div#target").append($(wrapper).append(innerHtmlAsText));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/511/)**